# what k8s-app label represent ? and how to use it?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

Hello I've been learning about Kubernetes but in a YAML file I found k8s-app as a label but when looking for an answer I really didn't find an accurate answer.
Please if someone has what does k8s-app stands for in YAML file help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, labels are key/value pairs that we can give to k8s objects. By using labels we can identify attributes of objects and also can select those objects by the selector. For example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
```

On the other hand, you there are basically 6 fields which you can set in your label, fields are:

```
apiVersion: 
kind: 
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: 
    app.kubernetes.io/instance:
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: 
    app.kubernetes.io/component:
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of:
```

Every object should have a unique name which is represented by `app.kubernetes.io/name`, it also can have an `instance` label, a `version`, a `who manages the object`, a `component type`, and a `part of what` object is. These labels are used previously, but now they are not commonly used.

From k8s official [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/common-labels/#web-application-with-a-database), the following Deployment is used for WordPress:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: wordpress
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: wordpress-abcxzy
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "4.9.4"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: helm
    app.kubernetes.io/component: server
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: wordpress
```

Comment: Oh okay, thank you very much for your answer it was pretty detailed :)

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't stand for anything; it's just an older convention that has been superseded by the [new `app.kubernetes.io/` nomenclature](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/common-labels/#labels)

The old style was likely replaced by the new "namespaced" style to allow users to have their own `k8s-app:` or `instance:` or other "common" names without colliding with the labels that were used by the Deployment controllers for managing Pod lifecycles

tl;dr = it's not important what the text is, it's import that the text match up in the multiple places that reference it, as those labels are a contract between a few moving parts